# Maximum in given series.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Find the maximum term among, $1$, $2^{\frac{1}{2}}$, $3^{\frac{1}{3}}$, $4^{\frac{1}{4}}$, $...$

Now, if we take $f(x) = x^\frac{1}{x}$, and differentiate it is quite simple to see that it reaches it's maximum value at $x=e$ and is increasing on the left of $e$ and decreasing on the right.

Thus it's obvious that the maxium is either the $\sqrt2$ or $3^\frac{1}{3}$. Now it seems that since $3$ is closer to $e$ than $2$, the greater value should be at $3$ which I confirmed using a calculator, but I can't seem to figure out how to go about proving it on paper, any help?

The curve isn't symmetrical either, so the *closer* argument isn't very reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a = 2^{1/2}$ and $b = 3^{1/3}$. Then

$$a^6 = 2^{6/2} = 8$$

while $$b^6 = 3^{6/3} = 9$$

Since $t \mapsto t^6$ is monotone increasing, the result follows.

Comment: whoa, man that was obvious and embarrassing. Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: @Sabyasachi You're very welcome; it's a useful trick to exponentiate creatively.

Comment: I'll remember that. I once had to find which was greater pi to the power e or e to the power pi, and I proved that e to the power 1/e was greater than pi to the power 1/pi and raised both sides to the power (pi*e). It is useful. :). For some reason I can't seem to tag you though.

Comment: also, nitpick: shouldn't that be since t->t^6 is monotone increasing for t>0? I don't fuss about this kind of stuff but since you wrote that anyway, so?

Comment: @Sabyasachi Yes, it's only monotone for $t > 0$; I didn't mention it since you're only dealing with positive numbers here.